# Do Jews need to kasher pots and glasses used for Yayin Nesech

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, yoreh-deah, yayin-nesech

According to Halacha, if there is a glass or pot that has been covered in Yayin Nesech wine do Jews have to kasher it in order to use it for kosher food or drink? Or is merely washing it enough? To clarify I’m talking about Yayin stam which is rabbinic not genuinely biblically prohibited  wine offered to idols.

Comment: Cold wine wouldn't be absorbed so there is no question. You might be asking about wine in a hot pot?

Comment: I asked the question and was told even a becher that was used for cold wine needs to be kashered

Comment: Answer is in שולחן ערוך, יורה דעה קל״ה - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.135.1